# How to count the number of delimiter-separated strings in a line

Tags: c++, csv

I have a file which looks like this:

```
2,1,4,6,7
1,2,3,6,5
```

I have to count the the digits in a single line while ignoring the comma. For example, the first line has 5 digits, and so does the second line. The number of digits can vary in each line. I used `getline` with a comma delimeter. However, if I do that, I don't know when the line ends. The code I have written will give me the count for whole file. All I want is a way to count the digits in a single line. How do I do that?

```
numberofdigits = 0;

while(!friendsFile.eof())
{       
    getline(friendsFile,counts,',');
    intcounts = stoi(counts);
    cout << intcounts;
    numberofdigits++;
}
```

Comment: `while(!friendsFile.eof())` Ouch. [c++ - Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: If you want to read a line of input, that's what `std::getline` is for. After you've read one line, then you can figure out how many comma-delimited values it has.

Comment: I have tried it too. It doesn't helps. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Of course, it helps. It's very easy to do. Unfortunately, "it doesn't help" is not a useful problem description that anyone else can use to give you further advice.

Comment: while(!friendsFile.eof()){
 getline(friendsFile,counts);
 intcounts = (stoi(counts.substr(counts.find(',')-1,1)));
 cout << intcounts;
 }

Comment: This is what i did. It gives an exception

Comment: Can you explain in detail how i can count the digits in a single line? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Why, iterate over each character in the line, of course. For each character in the string: is this character a digit? If so, increment the counter. And the end of the line you have your count. Which part of this basic task you're not sure about?

Comment: How do i get the length of whole line? I used strlen but it gives error. It says "no suitable conversion from string to const char exists "

Answer (score 0):

Combine your solution with reading line by line, and with a little help of [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input{"input.txt"};

    if(!input) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::size_t line_number = 0;
    std::istringstream stream{};

    for(std::string line{}; std::getline(input, line); stream.clear()) {
        stream.str(line);
        std::size_t count = 0;
        std::string number{};

        while(std::getline(stream, number, ',')) {
            ++count;
        }

        std::cout << "Line " << line_number++ << " contains " << count << " digits\n";
    }
}
```

After you make sure that the file was opened successfully, you can start processing the file.

First, pay attention to the `for()` loop. We use a `line` string to save a line read from the file. The condition of the loop is *also* the part where we read the line. `std::getline` not only reads a line, but also returns the stream from where it was reading. That stream can be *implicitely convered to `bool` to check whether the stream is in a valid state*. By doing that, we are reading the file line by line *and* making sure that if something goes wrong (i.e., we reach end of the file), we won't enter the loop and use, potentially corrupted, data. That's a big difference between using this method and `!file.eof()`, which is [almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Then, after reading a line, we initialize an `std::istringstream` object with it. Stringstreams are useful helpers which enable us to operate on text as though it was a stream. We again use `std::getline`, but this time to extract all the tokens separated by `','`.

The `stream.clear()` part in necessary after we process a single line, because it clears all bad states of the stream (i.e., the state of reaching end of file - in our case, after reading the whole line).

We count the number of successfull extractions and display it on the screen.